# using HashMap adding/retrieving and more

Tags: java, hashmap

EDITS: I have two other classes called CheckingAccount and SavingsAccount. I am adding my Account code down as well.

I have a class Account and working on another class Ledger which is a 'HAS-A' relationship with Account. In Ledger, I use a HashMap<>() to create a storage system for the different accounts. I think I have most of the coding correct, expect the last two methods. If someone can explains or give the nodge in the right direction for the last two methods, and go over my other work, that would help also. Below each method is a comment block of what the method is supposed to do and return. Thanks.

```
/**
 * @author Deborah
 *
 */
public abstract class Account {

protected String accountID;
protected double balance;
protected String accountType;
protected String firstName;
protected String lastName;

public String getAccountID() {
    return this.accountID;
}

public double getBalance() {
    return this.balance ;
}

public String getAccountType() {
    return this.accountType;
} 

public String getFirstName() {
    return this.firstName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return this.lastName;
}

public void setAccountID(String accountID) {
    this.accountID = accountID;
}

public void setBalance(double balance) {
    this.balance = balance;
}

public void setAccountType(String accountType) {
    this.accountType = accountType;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

public String toString() {
    return "Account ID: " + accountID + "\n" +
            "Account Type: " + accountType + "\n" +
            "Balance: $" + balance + "\n";
}

public abstract IAccountManager getAccountManager();
```

}

```
public class Ledger {
    //the single instance of Ledger
    private static final Ledger instance = new Ledger();

    //create accounts: Map<String, Account>
    //use to add an Account, retrieve an Account, ect...

    HashMap<String, Account> accounts = new HashMap<>();

    //private constructor    
    private Ledger() {}

    //method to return the single instance
    public static Ledger getInstance(){
        return instance;
    }

    public boolean store(Account account) {
        /* adds a new Account to the accounts Map. The key is the account’s ID. This
         * method should return a Boolean object that is "true" when the Account added
         * to the ledger is being added for the first time, "false" if it is being
         * updated. Check the documentation for the Map.put() method for reference.
         */
        String key = account.getAccountID();
        if(accounts.put(key, account) != null){
            accounts.put(key, account);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }   


    public Account retrieve() { 
        /* returns a single Account with the specified accountID from the accounts Map.
         * If none is found, return null.
         */ 
        Account account = new Account();
        String key = account.getAccountID();
        if(accounts.containsKey(key)) {
            return account;
        }
        return null;
    }


    public Account createAccount(Account account) {
        /* this method creates and returns a new Account object with the specified
         * parameters (type, firstName, lastName). Calling this method should store the
         * new account within the accounts Map. Please note the first parameter passed
         * into this method determines which account type (CheckingAccount vs.
         * SavingsAccount) to create. The values should either be “checking” or
         * “savings”.
         */
        String key = account.getAccountType();

        if(accounts.containsKey("Checking")) {                          
            accounts.put(key,account);
            return account;
        }else{
            accounts.put(key,account);
            return account;

        }
    }

    public Account getNextAccountID() {
        /*this is a helper method that can be used to find out what the next 
         * accountID will be based on the number of Accounts within the accounts Map.
         * It should return the size of the accounts Map plus one.
         */ 

        return accounts.size() + 1;
    }

    public Ledger getAllAccounts() {
        /*this method returns a list of all the Accounts w/in the accounts Map
         */
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that the return type for `getAllAccounts()` is supposed to be `Ledger`?  It seems to me that if you're calling this method, you've already got a `Ledger` object.

Comment: I am not sure about anything really on the last to methods. I am even thinking that the return type for getNextAccountID should be an int.

Comment: Yes, I think you're right about `getNextAccountId`.  As for `getAllAccounts`, your description suggests that it should return `List<Account>`.  If that's the case, does the list have to be in any particular order?

Comment: Few things: 1) if accounts.put returns != null, there is no reason to "put" it again.  2) retrieve() is not returning the Account from the hashmap.  3) in createAccount, what is "checking" (violates the idea that the Map is keyed by account ID)  - and don't have an "if" where both branches do the same thing. 4) getNextAccountId - Decide whether you want Account.id to be a String or an Integer, and declare your HashMap in line with that.

Comment: can you please post your code for `Account` class? 1 more thing `createAccount` looks fishy to me. You are adding **Checking** and **Savings** as a key here while key is the `accountId` for the map in other functions

Comment: I have editted the question, added in more details, and added the code for the Account class. The list<Acount> does not have to be in order.

Comment: for getAllAccounts, consider WHY you want this.  You could be effectively breaking encapsulation.  Do you want to save, or print, the accounts?  Maybe add a method with a lambda parameter, and let class Ledger do the looping?   If printing, do you want it sorted by Account.id, and will this be a common required use case?  If so, maybe consider replacing HashMap (effectively random ordering, but fast adding/retrieving individual accounts) by TreeMap (implicitly sorted - but slower in adding/retrieving individual accounts).

Comment: @racraman I suspect the reason is probably ... Deborah wants getAllAccounts because her teacher has told her she has to have it.

Comment: Thanks everyone for helping!!! Y'all rock!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note: I changed my `hashmap` key to int, if you want to use String then you need to make necessary changes**

**changes to store account**

Your condition to check if account is already exists is wrong, you can not use `put` method for that instead use `containsKey`

```
public boolean store(Account account) {
    /* adds a new Account to the accounts Map. The key is the account’s ID. This
     * method should return a Boolean object that is "true" when the Account added
     * to the ledger is being added for the first time, "false" if it is being
     * updated. Check the documentation for the Map.put() method for reference.
     */
    int key = account.getAccountID();
    if(accounts.containsKey(key) != null){
        accounts.put(key, account);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

**Changes for the `retrieve` method:**

This method is being used to fetch an account so need to create a new `account` instance here. It's clearly specified that if you don't find an account then return `null`.

> returns a single Account with the specified accountID from the accounts Map.

This means method should have `accountId` as a parameter and then we need to search it in our map.

```
public Account retrieve(int accountId) { 
    /* returns a single Account with the specified accountID from the accounts Map.
     * If none is found, return null.
     */ 
    if(accounts.containsKey(accountId)) {
        return accounts.get(accountId);
    }
    return null;
}
```

**changes to `createAccount`:**

1) Passing parameters (type, firstName and lastName) as specified in your spec

2) Your hashmap key will be now `int` as we returns an `int` from our `getNextAccountID` method. This makes more sense to me.

3) Calling `getNextAccountID` from this function as it's needed to create a new account.

4) I am assuming that you have constructor in your `SavingAccount` and `CheckingAccount` class. if you do not then please create one or use set methods after initializing with default constructor. Your constructor should assign balance value to 0.

```
public Account createAccount(String accountType, String firstName, String lastName) {
    /* this method creates and returns a new Account object with the specified
     * parameters (type, firstName, lastName). Calling this method should store the
     * new account within the accounts Map. Please note the first parameter passed
     * into this method determines which account type (CheckingAccount vs.
     * SavingsAccount) to create. The values should either be “checking” or
     * “savings”.
     */

    int accountId = getNextAccountID();
    Account acc;
    if(type == "checking"){
      acc = new CheckingAccount(id, type, firstName, lastName);
    } else {
      acc = new SavingAccount(id, type, firstName, lastName);
    }
    return acc;
}
```

**Changes to `getNextAccountID`:**

1) Returning an integer (you can change it to long if you want)

```
public Integer getNextAccountID() {
    /*this is a helper method that can be used to find out what the next 
     * accountID will be based on the number of Accounts within the accounts Map.
     * It should return the size of the accounts Map plus one.
     */ 

    return accounts.size() + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all this methode getNextAccountID should return  an int

and for the seconde one i suggest

```
 public List<Account> getAllAccounts() {
        Set<Account> allaccounts = accounts.values(); 
        LinkedList<Account> l ; 
        l.addAll(allacounts);
        return l; 
  }
```

in my suggest , i've tried to save the accounts in a set  using the methode values in the interface map and then add all the accounts saved in the set in a list  and finally return the list  , I hoped it would be useful.